# UIAlertView loading indicator is almost offside?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have following code:

```
_loadingAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:ALERT_TITLE_LOADING
                                           message:ALERT_MESSAGE_LOADING
                                          delegate:nil
                                 cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[indicator startAnimating];

[_loadingAlert setValue:indicator forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[_loadingAlert show];
```

Result:

[image]

My purpose is to display an alertview with loading indicator inside but the result is as attached screenshot. Anyone has idea?

Comment: Have you noticed that `UIAlertView` has been deprecated for a while now? You should use `UIAlertController` instead.

Comment: Yes I note on that, but I still need to support iOS 7..

Comment: Try a custom view that would have an inset at the bottom, the progress view doesn't have it.

Comment: Add cancel button title to cancel. What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: A-Live: We cannot add custom view using addSubview. I also tried to use UIView to addSubview the loading indicator (then set them as accessories in UIAlertView), but the loading indicator cannot be centred. Ersin: cancel is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code (as suggested by @A-Live), you can adjust the padding value to add more space at the bottom of the activity indicator.

```
_loadingAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:ALERT_TITLE_LOADING
                                           message:ALERT_MESSAGE_LOADING
                                          delegate:nil
                                 cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
indicator.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
indicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
[indicator startAnimating];

CGFloat padding = 15;
UIView *indicatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, indicator.frame.size.width, indicator.frame.size.width+padding)];
[indicatorView addSubview:indicator];

[_loadingAlert setValue:indicatorView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[_loadingAlert show];
```